# Deleted Terraria world

Tags: terraria-mobile

I deleted my best Terraria world, and my only one, with no backup. I don't have a computer. Is there any other way to get it back? I'm literally gonna die.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I did not notice that this question was regarding the mobile version of terraria. The only thing you can really do is check whether or not the files still exist using either [i-funbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) or [iTools](http://www.itools.cn/multi_lang_pc_download.htm). If your device has a form of temporary data then your file could be recoverable.

Comment: op is asking for terraria mobile

Comment: oops my bad! Sorry about the mistake